# Square-connect Missing required parameter: idempotency_key, NodeJS

Tags: node.js, square-connect

Everytime I try to create an order via the square-connect api, I get the following error:

```
{"errors": [{"code": "MISSING_REQUIRED_PARAMETER","detail": "Missing required parameter.","field": "idempotency_key","category": "INVALID_REQUEST_ERROR"}]}.
```

I believe I am including the idempotency_key correctly in the request, however I just keep receiving the same error. Any ideas on how I could fix this?

```
router.post(
    '/startorder',
    [
        check('email', 'Please enter your email').not().isEmpty(),
        check('email', 'Please enter a valid email').isEmail(),
        check('address', 'Please enter your address').not().isEmpty(),
        check('zipCode', 'Please enter your zipcode').not().isEmpty(),
        check('name', 'Please enter your name').not().isEmpty(),
        check('city', 'Please enter your city').not().isEmpty(),
        check('country', 'Please enter your country').not().isEmpty(),
        check('state', 'Please enter your state').not().isEmpty(),
    ],
    async (req, res) => {
        const errors = validationResult(req);

        if (!errors.isEmpty()) {
            return res.status(400).json({ errors: errors.array() });
        }

        const { email, address, zipCode, name, city, country, state } = req.body;

        const apiInstance = new SquareConnect.OrdersApi();

        const locationId = process.env.LOCATION_ID; // String | The ID of the business location to associate the order with.

        const request_body = {
            order: {
                location_id: locationId,
            },
            idempotency_key: crypto.randomBytes(22).toString('hex'),
        };
        const body = new SquareConnect.CreateOrderRequest(request_body); 

        try {
            console.log('this is the body', body);
            const response = await apiInstance.createOrder(locationId, body);
            console.log(response);
            res.json(response);
        } catch (error) {
            console.error(error);
            return res.status(500).json({ msg: error });
        }
    }
);
```